# Serving static assets with Dropwizard

Tags: java, rest, dropwizard

Dropwizard version 1.3.0-rc6

Most documentation regarding serving static content are for older versions, and even the updated docs in [Dropwizard Manual](http://www.dropwizard.io/1.3.1/docs/manual/core.html) aren't exactly working for me.

I want to serve a static html file. I have modified the structure/paths of where these assets are served from, but can't quite get the configuration right in my environment.

Static content is located under the following structure

---

```
src/main/
├── java
│   └── org
│       └── com
│           └── query
│       
│               ├── rest
│               │   ├── api
│               │   ├── cli
│               │   ├── core
│               │   ├── db
│               │   ├── health
│               │   ├── resources
│               │   ├── tasks
│               │   └── views
│    
├── resources
│   ├── META-INF
│   │   ├── bin-license-notice
│   │   │   └── licenses
│   │   └── services
│   └── rest
│       ├── ftl
│       └── mustache
└── webapp
    ├── WEB-INF
    │   └── views
    │       └── jsp
    └── resources
        └── core
            ├── css
            └── js
```

`multiFileUpload.html` is inside `src/main/webapp/resources/core` dir, which is ultimately what I want to serve. However, this is different than dropwizard standards of `src/main/resources/assets/`.

I need the extended constructor to specify the individual AssetBundles as I plan on having multiple instances of `AssetBundle`. This is what I have inside my application initialize method.

`@Override
public void initialize(Bootstrap<HelloWorldConfiguration> bootstrap) {
    bootstrap.addBundle(new AssetsBundle("/webapp/resources/core/*", "/", null, "/MultiFileUpload.html"));
}`

I have also set a urlPattern in the applications run method.
`environment.jersey().setUrlPattern("/rest/*");`

The root path in my config.yml is `rootPath:/rest/*`

I have an endpoint that the .html file should be served at. `localhost:port/rest/upload/multiFile`

I'm almost certain one of these paths is incorrect but I have tried to change them according to documentation examples, but haven't had any luck.

Comment: How are you running Dropwizard? Gradle? Maven? IDEA? i suspect your problem is that `webapp` isn't part of any of your resource paths so DW can't see it.  Try mounting it as an absolute path, if that works, it's a classpath issue

Comment: I'm running with maven. `webapp` is simply a sub-dir containing the static content. The file upload service itself has been registered in the environment configuration of my DW app. I'll see what providing the full absolute path does. @tddmonkey

Comment: I opted to move it under the conventional structure that dropwizard has. Still can't get the .html file to show up at the desired endpoint

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I just posted an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52500362/dropwizard-unable-to-serve-static-html/52509955#52509955) to a similar question. I will list them here as well,

1. AssetBundle path is calculated from project resources folder. Therefore add path relative to that. Here `assets` directory is located in `${Project Root}/src/main/resources` directory

   ```
   bootstrap.addBundle(new AssetsBundle("/assets/", "/"));
   ```
2. Remove explicit Jersey registry entry. I believe this is inherited from configuration.

   ```
   environment.jersey().setUrlPattern("/*"); /*this line should be removed*/
   ```

You will need to included [`dropwizard-assets`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.dropwizard/dropwizard-assets) to your project's dependencies.

For easy reference I created a [sample project](https://github.com/theisuru/dropwizard-features) with static assets.