# Dropwizard: Unable to serve static HTML

Tags: java, html, static, dropwizard, serving

I'm currently working on serving a static html page in Dropwizard at the root path "/".  So far, I've only received an error page stating "HTTP ERROR 404 Problem accessing /. Reason: Not Found".

I've followed the [Dropwizard documentation for 1.2.2](https://www.dropwizard.io/1.2.2/docs/manual/core.html#serving-assets) in doing this, as well as this tutorial [here](https://spin.atomicobject.com/2014/10/11/serving-static-assets-with-dropwizard/), with some changes to the code for my services to work.  My root path in my .yml file is `/profile/v1` to allow my getAll services to work (when I first started, I was getting an error for having `Multiple servlets map to path /*`.  The .yml looks like this:

```
server:
  type: simple
  applicationContextPath: /
  rootPath: /profile/v1
```

In addition, my initialize in the main application class is:

```
@Override
public void initialize(final Bootstrap<AutomationConfigServiceConfiguration> bootstrap) {
    bootstrap.addBundle(new AssetsBundle("/../resources", "/", "index.html"));
}
```

This is registered to jersey as:

```
environment.jersey().setUrlPattern("/*");
```

where `/resources` is the directory I'm keeping my static assets, outside of the `java` directory.

So far, I've been able to get my services to work fine in this setup.  For example, when I go to localhost:8080/profile/v1/name/getAll, I'm able to retrieve all the names from the database, and if I go to localhost:8080/profile/v1/titles/getAll, I get all titles from the database.  If I use localhost:8080, with or without a "/", I just get a 404 page, saying it cannot find "/".  In theory, this should be very simple, so I'm unsure what else I should do.

Edit:

When I go to /profile/v1, I get the following:

```
{
code: 404,
message: "HTTP 404 Not Found",
}
```

I should mention that I don't want my html to be served here;  I'd like for it to be served at root, as the path /profile/v1 is used by all my services.  This was requested to help set up DNS.

Comment: As to my understanding, your static page should be available from `localhost:8080/profile/v1`

Comment: Doing this brings up a 404 json response. I'll edit the question to include this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After couple of modifications to your code, got it to working condition.

1. AssetBundle path is calculated from project resources folder. Therefore add path relative to that. Here `assets` directory is located in `${Project Root}/src/main/resources` directory

   ```
   bootstrap.addBundle(new AssetsBundle("/assets/", "/"));
   ```
2. Remove explicit Jersey registry entry. I believe this is inherited from configuration.

   ```
   environment.jersey().setUrlPattern("/*"); /*this line should be removed*/
   ```

You will need to included [`dropwizard-assets`](http://You%20will%20need%20to%20included%20[%60dropwizard-assets%60][2]%20to%20your%20project's%20dependencies.) to your project's dependencies.

For reference, just created a [sample project](https://github.com/theisuru/dropwizard-features) with static assets.