# How to add openapi.yaml to your project

Tags: java, swagger, openapi, dropwizard

How to add openapi.yaml to an existing project with already written code for REST API?
In what folder should I put the yaml file and what "configuration" needs to be done for it to work properly (display swagger UI)?

Note: using dropwizard framework

Comment: are you using a build tool, like gradle/maven?

Comment: did you hand-write the YAML or is it generated through your code?

Comment: @ToxicWaste
I am using maven, the yaml file is hand-written

Comment: The easyest way is to put your YAML into resources and publish it as a static file (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50105102/serving-static-assets-with-dropwizard). For a nice representation just refer your customers to paste the contents to https://editor.swagger.io/ . We did the same to avoid managing the swagger UI ourselves.

Comment: @ToxicWaste Thanks for the answer, I tried this and it works nicely. However, is there a way to provide customers swagger UI without instructing them to go to swagger editor?

Comment: @randomguy I have not done it, since in our case the YAML was mostly internal documentation and the UI not worth the effort. But you could look into https://github.com/smoketurner/dropwizard-swagger. The readme shows how to use annotations - but there may be a way to just feed it the YAML statically. When you find out, please let us know how ;-)

Comment: @ToxicWaste 
I can't find where it explains annotations in the readme. I only see a link which leads to nowhere useful. Can you elaborate?

Comment: look at this line: https://github.com/smoketurner/dropwizard-swagger/blob/72e8441e4a09dca6e9c1afe0fd05c7a85935531d/README.md?plain=1#L68 it calls for a list of the packages containing your ```@Api``` annotations. I don't know whether you can just give them a hand written yaml...

Answer (score 0):

I was running into several issues myself using Open API with Spring/Dropwizard. So I started building an alternative that makes repo integration easier (https://github.com/fern-api/fern).

Steps to get started:

1. You can install it with `npm install -g fern-api`
2. Run `fern init` which will create an api directory that has an API definition
3. Run `fern add java` to add the java generator
4. Run `fern generate` to generate the java subproject
5. Add a dependency on the java subproject and implement your APIs

https://docs.buildwithfern.com/#/ There's a video here on how to get started with Java.

If you want to add an `openapi.yml` after, you will be able to convert the fern api definition into a valid Open API.

Apologies if this wasn't the answer you were looking for, just figured I'd share an alternative that might solve your problem!